# How to get a "data-value” attribute updated in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

Got a data-attribute bound to an Angular2 variable. That works fine. But a method might change the value, which is MOSTLY not reflected in the data-attribute. Any idea how to solve this? Here a simplified example:

```
<span (click)="addMoney(item)">
  <i class="money inline icon right"  attr.data-content="Click amount to donate ${{item.step}}"></i>
</span>
```

So, in this example, assume that `addMoney()` can change "item.step". 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: And the code you provided doesn't work?

Comment: That should just work.

Comment: No, it does not work! When make a method out of it, say {{ getStep() }}, then the method is called, but the text stays the same. Semantic UI problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap `attr.data-content` in square brackets and string value in single quotes like below and remove curly brackets.

```
  <span (click)="addMoney(item)">
      <i class="money inline icon right"
        [data-content]="'Click amount to donate ' + item.step"></i>
    </span>
```

Comment: Doesn't work either... Looks like Angular2 `learns` from history: if "item.step" is not changed the firts clicks, it will never change (for data-content). If it changes the first click(s), it does adjust the data-content attribute.

Comment: I just realised it should not be `attr.data-content` but `data-content`. Let me know if this works.